# How can I set the value of c when generating a Mandelbrot fractal?

Tags: java, math, fractals, mandelbrot

The equation for generating a Mandelbrot fractal is `Zn+1 = Zn^2+C`. The issue is that, in a computer program, C is used for zoom/resolution and location on screen. My question is, how can I make it so that I can get a fractal like this:

[Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MandelbrotSet.html)

(`equation f(z) = sin(z/c), z0 = c` )

[image: cassinioval]

My code (from [Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#Java)):

```
public class MandelbrotSet extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5513426498262284949L;
    private final int MAX_ITER = 570;
    private final double ZOOM = 150;
    private BufferedImage image;
    private double zx, zy, cX, cY, tmp;

    public MandelbrotSet() {
        super("Mandelbrot Set");
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        image = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x++) {
                zx = zy = 0;
                cX = (x - 400) / ZOOM;
                cY = (y - 300) / ZOOM;
                int iter = MAX_ITER;

                while (zx * zx + zy * zy < 4 && iter > 0) {
                    tmp = zx * zx - zy * zy + cX;
                    zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cY;
                    zx = tmp;
                    iter--;
                }

                image.setRGB(x, y, iter | (iter << 8));
            }
        }
    }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MandelbrotSet().setVisible(true);;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to get local variables that cover the zoom window? Or how to implement the sine for complex arguments? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trigonometric theorems

```
sin(A+i*B)=sin(A)*cos(i*B)+  cos(A)*sin(i*B) 
          =sin(A)*cosh(B )+i*cos(A)*sinh(B )
```

and for the quotient using `z=x+i*y` and `c=a+i*b`

```
(x+i*y)/(a+i*b)=(x+i*y)*(a-i*b)/(a*a+b*b)
```

so that for the sine expression above

```
A = (a*x+b*y)/(a*a+b*b)
B = (a*y-b*x)/(a*a+b*b)
```

---

In javascript a small script to generate this fractal can look like this:

```js
function cosh(x) { return 0.5*(Math.exp(x)+Math.exp(-x)); }
function sinh(x) { return 0.5*(Math.exp(x)-Math.exp(-x)); }

function rgb(r,g,b) { return "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"; }
var colors = new Array(24);
for(var k=0; k<8; k++) {
    colors[   k] = rgb(k*64,(7-k)*64,(7-k)*64);
    colors[ 8+k] = rgb((7-k)*64,k*64,(7-k)*64);
    colors[16+k] = rgb((7-k)*64,(7-k)*64,k*64);
}

var cvs = document.getElementById('sine-fractal');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
var cx = 0.0, cy = 0.0;
var dx = 1.0;

var tiles = 100;
var scale = Math.min(cvs.width, cvs.height) / tiles;
ctx.scale(scale, scale);

function localx(i) { return cx-dx + 2*i*dx/tiles; }
function localy(j) { return cy-dx + 2*j*dx/tiles; }

for (var i = 0; i < tiles; i++) {
  var a = localx(i);
  for (var j = 0; j < tiles; j++) {
    var b = localy(j);
    var r2 = a*a + b*b;
    var x = a, y = b;
    var rounds = 0;
    var max = 500;
    while (x * x + y * y < 4 && rounds < max) {
      var u = (a*x + b*y) / r2, v = (a*y - b*x) / r2;
      x = Math.sin(u) * cosh(v);
      y = Math.cos(u) * sinh(v);
      rounds++;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = colors[rounds % 24];
    ctx.fillRect(i, j, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id='sine-fractal' width=200 height=200></canvas>
```